# OpenCV: How to use other font than HERSHEY with cvPutText (like Arial)

Tags: image, opencv, truetype

I want to write to an image a formatted text. OpenCV offers only a limited set of default fonts. Is it possible to use others? For example to read them from the *.ttf file (in Ubuntu)?

Comment: Have a look at the link http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/drawing_functions.html#cv-puttext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use other fonts but you need to link the Qt library to OpenCV and use the cvAddText function with a cvFontQt

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html#addtext

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html#fontqt

There are other solutions you might try, with more or less the same performance as OpenCV. For instance, you can use CAIRO to write fonts into the image.

Answer (score 13):

If you cannot or don't want to use the Qt bindings, here is a way to do it with CAIRO:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cairo/cairo.h>
#include <string>

void putTextCairo(
        cv::Mat &targetImage,
        std::string const& text,
        cv::Point2d centerPoint,
        std::string const& fontFace,
        double fontSize,
        cv::Scalar textColor,
        bool fontItalic,
        bool fontBold)
{
    // Create Cairo
    cairo_surface_t* surface =
            cairo_image_surface_create(
                CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
                targetImage.cols,
                targetImage.rows);

    cairo_t* cairo = cairo_create(surface);

    // Wrap Cairo with a Mat
    cv::Mat cairoTarget(
                cairo_image_surface_get_height(surface),
                cairo_image_surface_get_width(surface),
                CV_8UC4,
                cairo_image_surface_get_data(surface),
                cairo_image_surface_get_stride(surface));

    // Put image onto Cairo
    cv::cvtColor(targetImage, cairoTarget, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA);

    // Set font and write text
    cairo_select_font_face(
                cairo,
                fontFace.c_str(),
                fontItalic ? CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_ITALIC : CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,
                fontBold ? CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD : CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);

    cairo_set_font_size(cairo, fontSize);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cairo, textColor[2], textColor[1], textColor[0]);

    cairo_text_extents_t extents;
    cairo_text_extents(cairo, text.c_str(), &extents);

    cairo_move_to(
                cairo,
                centerPoint.x - extents.width/2 - extents.x_bearing,
                centerPoint.y - extents.height/2- extents.y_bearing);
    cairo_show_text(cairo, text.c_str());

    // Copy the data to the output image
    cv::cvtColor(cairoTarget, targetImage, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);

    cairo_destroy(cairo);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
}
```

Example call:

```cpp
putTextCairo(mat, "Hello World", cv::Point2d(50,50), "arial", 15, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), false, false);
```

It assumes that the target image is BGR.

It puts the text's center to the given point. If you want some different positioning, you have to modify the `cairo_move_to` call.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But is 'centerAnchor' referring to 'centerPoint'? And how can we install the Cairo in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @user1098761 `sudo apt install libcairo2-dev`. If you are using CMake, you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636886/cairo-library-and-cmake . I used FindCairo.cmake from WebKit.