# Cairo library and Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, cairo

I'm new to c++ and cmake. I installed cairo library as written [here](https://cairographics.org/download/) via port. Now i want to include cairo to my project. I wrote the CmakeLists.txt commands as shown [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(HelloOpenGL)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(HelloOpenGL ${SOURCE_FILES})

#find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
#include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#target_link_libraries(HelloOpenGL ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})

find_package(Cairo)
include_directories(${Cairo_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(HelloOpenGL ${Cairo_LIBRARIES})

if(CAIRO_FOUND)
    message("Cairo found")
    else()
    message("Cairo not found")
    endif()
```

But it's not working, I get this output -

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCairo.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Cairo", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Cairo" with any of
  the following names:

    CairoConfig.cmake
    cairo-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Cairo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Cairo_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Cairo"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Help me to properly include cairo, please

Comment: which version of CMake are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your version of CMake doesn't have (by the way, not even the latest development version of CMake has it ... https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/tree/master/Modules)
the file `FindCairo.cmake` that you need to have to run the command `find_package(Cairo)` and you haven't included this file in your package.
A solution is to grab a `FindCairo.cmake` file from the web, create a `cmake` directory inside the root directory of your project and have in `CMakeLists.txt` the extra line

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
```

so your snippet from `CMakeLists.txt` would look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(HelloOpenGL)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(HelloOpenGL ${SOURCE_FILES})

#find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
#include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#target_link_libraries(HelloOpenGL ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})

find_package(Cairo)
include_directories(${Cairo_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(HelloOpenGL ${Cairo_LIBRARIES})
```

If you will not use an already existing `FindCairo.cmake` (e.g. Cairo that you installed might contain one such file) you will have to write one or find an alternative way to include the package.

Comment: I tried what this, but the problem was solved only when I reinstalled cairo through `brew install cairo`. Now there's a new problem. The IDE cannot find include<cairo.h> . But include<cairo/cairo.h> working well.

Comment: However, I get this error message on compilation:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cairo_arc", referenced from:
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [HelloOpenGL] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloOpenGL.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloOpenGL.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [HelloOpenGL] Error 2`